# Since wireshark can decrypt the WPA2-PSK with known SSID and PSK, how to protect it for personal usage

Tags: wireless-networking, encryption, wireshark

Referring the introduce of [HowToDecrypt802.11](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) WPA2-PSK can be Decrypted when knowing the SSID and PSK.
While a Wi-Fi sniffer can monitor it easily (e.g : macbook sniffer tool)
How can we protect it for personal usage.

Comment: Use a PSK which is not easy to guess. https://www.techopedia.com/definition/22921/wi-fi-protected-access-pre-shared-key-wpa-psk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I I know, you cannot prevent this in WPA2-PSK. Depending on what your devices support, you would need to switch either to WPA3-SAE or to WPA2-EAP/Enterprise (using EAP-TTLS or EAP-PEAP, which use standard TLS for the session key generation).